# Using moment.twitter.js with requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, momentjs

I'm using momentjs for my backbone project with requirejs. Everthing works fine the following way

```
require.config({

baseUrl : 'js/',

urlArgs: 'bust=' +  ( new Date() ).getTime(),

paths: {
    jquery      : 'libs/jquery-2.0.3.min',
    underscore  : 'libs/underscore-min',
    backbone    : 'libs/backbone-min',
    moment      : 'libs/moment-2.3.1.min',
    momenttweet : 'libs/moment.twitter',
},

shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    backbone: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    moment: {
        exports: 'moment'
    },
    momenttweet: {
        deps: ['moment'],
        exports: 'moment'
    }

}
});
```

The above config breaks when I build using r.js to get .min file

Any solution to make it work.
Source of Moment.twitter
https://github.com/SpiderStrategies/moment.twitter

Or any idea how to make moment.twitter AMD Compatible

Answer (score 0):

I tried wrapping up the moment.twitter within define call and removed the momemnt.twitter from the dependency and the shim

```
define([
  'moment'
], function( moment ) {
       var second = 1e3, minute = 6e4, hour = 36e5, day = 864e5, week = 6048e5;
       var formats = {
          seconds: {
          short: 's',
          long: ' sec'
          ...
          ...
          ...

  return moment;
});
```

and include the above file as a dependency in files where the moment.twitter is required and call it as moment.twitterShort();